# How to map an error using dSYM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I am a bit unfamiliar with how this works, so excuse any ignorance here. I have a crash log that looks like this:

```
Crashed Thread: 6
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x18eb7a014 __pthread_kill (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x18eaee3f4 abort (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 140
2   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x10041594c 0x1000dc000 + 3381580
3   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x1003f8440 0x1000dc000 + 3261504
4   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x1003f8634 0x1000dc000 + 3262004
5   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x1002cdcc4 0x1000dc000 + 2038980
6   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x1003eb6b8 0x1000dc000 + 3208888
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x18ec3f860 _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x18ec3f770 _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x18ec3cdbc thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

And I have a dSYM file, which I know is supposed to make sense of this, but my question is, how do I actually do it? I've seen some examples from users who have XCode builds in native ObjC/Swift. My issue is that I am using Xamarin on Visual Studio, and all I have is this log. I want to figure out how I can use the dSYM to make sense of these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to symbolicate the crash log.

Here´s a nice guide: http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/

Comment: I actually did this and it didn't change `XamarinMobileiOS                    0x10041594c 0x1000dc000 + 3381580
3   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x1003f8440 0x1000dc000 + 3261504
4   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x1003f8634 0x1000dc000 + 3262004
5   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x1002cdcc4 0x1000dc000 + 2038980
6   XamarinMobileiOS                    0x1003eb6b8 0x1000dc000 + 3208888` at all?